# Import vaex error: PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, pydantic, vaex

I am using Sagemaker notebook and when importing vaex, I am getting the below error. the version of vaex I'm using is 4.16.0

PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/u/import-error

Anyone knows how to solve this?

I tried downgrading the pydantic library while installing vaex but that didn't help.

Comment: Well, this is what happens, when package dependencies are not properly restricted to specific major versions. You said you _"tried downgrading the pydantic library"_. What exactly does that mean? Because I am pretty sure this error should not occur with Pydantic v1 installed. Also there is already a [bug report](https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/2384) for this.

Comment: Thank you for the bug report, I used the version mentioned in the report, and import works. Previously I was trying a different version of pydantic and that didn't work.

Answer (score 23):

What i have done
[Migration Guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings)

```bash
pip install pydantic-settings
```

I replaced in my code:

```py
# from pydantic import BaseSettings # OLD
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings # NEW
```

Answer (score 5):

In `pydantic-V2`, Settings management has been moved to a separate package named `pydantic-settings`.

You can install it by `pip install pydantic-settings`.

If you still want to have V1-style settings management in `V2`, you can import it like:

```py
from pydantic.v1 import BaseSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find answer in the error log.

> pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

Read migration guide.

```
pip install bump-pydantic
cd ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages
bump-pydantic anaconda_cloud_auth
bump-pydantic anaconda_navigator
```

Answer (score 0):

!pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip

import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df.head()

from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport  # Assuming you have already imported df and it contains your DataFrame

profile = ProfileReport(df, explorative=True, dark_mode=True)
profile.to_file('output.html')

Comment: You can format your code by selecting the code and pressing (ctrl+K) for code formatting.